# Submit dialog form in Struts2

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

I´m learning Struts2/Hibernate/Jquery and I am unable to submit a dialog form to send an "alumno" object (alumno.nombre, etc) from jsp to action. addUser() method only validate form fields. I´m trying to replicate the same behaviour of an usual `<s:form>`, in order to call a method "guardar" and save alumno object in db.

**Jquery JSP:**

```
 dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 400,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Guardar": addUser,
     "Cerrar": function() {
       dialog.dialog( "close" );
     }
  },
  close: function() {
    form[ 0 ].reset();
    allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
  }
});
// Se ejecuta cuando ya se ha creado/editado un alumno 
form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addUser();
    alert("form");
});

$( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    dialog.dialog( "open" );
});
```

**JSP**

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Crear nuevo alumno">
    <p class="validateTips">Todos los campos del formulario son obligatorios.</p>
  <s:form id="formularioAlumnos" action="guardarAdminAlumno">
<fieldset>
  <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" name="alumno.nombre" id="nombre">
  <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
  <input type="text" name="alumno.apellidos" id="apellidos">

  <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
  <s:submit id="entrar" ctabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px"/>
</fieldset>
```

**struts.xml**

```
   <action name="*AdminAlumno" method="{1}" class="AdminGestAlumActionBean">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">gestionAlumnos</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: I´ve tried with `$("#formularioAlumnos").submit()` inside AddUser () but it doesnt submit this form and redirect to the same view (gestionAlumnos) executing guardar() method (`method="{1}"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was easier than I thought because calling the click event of submit button (`$("#entrar").click();`) did the thing.

This happens because I don´t understand how jquery and ajax work and to what end yet.